# Why can't I pass "window.location.reload" as an argument to setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I would love some insight into the error I am seeing in Safari and Chrome with the following line of code:

`setTimeout(window.location.reload, 250);`

Chrome reports:
`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

And Safari:
`TypeError: Type error`

In FireFox, the code runs fine.  Also, this code runs fine in each of the three browsers:

```
setTimeout((function() {
  window.location.reload();
}), 250);
```

Chrome and Safari have no issues with this code:

```
var say_hello = function () { alert("hello") };  
setTimeout(say_hello, 250);
```

What is special about `window.location.reload` that causes this error?

(not sure if it's useful or not, but here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goggin13/SQ7az/5/) illustrating this)

Comment: I'm glad I checked if this was going to cause a problem. =)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Because `reload()` needs `window.location` as `this`. In other words - it is a method of `window.location`. When you say:

```
var fun = window.location.reload;

fun();
```

You are calling `reload()` function without any `this` reference (or with implicit `window` reference).

This should work:

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 250);
```

The `window.location.reload.bind(window.location)` part means: take `window.location.reload` function and return a function that, when called, will use `window.location` as `this` reference inside `reload()`.

## See also

- [How can I pass an argument to a function called using setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572673)
- [Why doesn't console.log work when passed as a parameter to forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639167)
- [Preserve 'this' reference in javascript prototype event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100469)

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Good to know.  Any guesses why it does work in Firefox?

Comment: @goggin13: interesting... not sure. But certainly this is not portable.

Comment: Right, just curious.  Thanks for the `.bind` explanation, very informative!

Comment: @goggin13 Probably because of the same reason that you can now do `const log = console.log`. The runtime may have prebound that method for you since it's intended only for the singleton (`location` or `console`)

Answer (score 8):

There is another way of doing this, pretty simple, and no need of doing extra steps, bindings or stuff like that. When you use arrow functions instead of common functions in JS, the `this` context is included. So you could just as easily do the following:

```js
setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 250);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` must be bound to `location` when you call `reload`. It's same as trying:

```
var reload = window.location.reload;
reload();
```

`this` would be `window` in non-strict mode and `undefined` in strict mode which are both invalid.

in non-old browsers you can do instead:

`reload.call( location )`

or in your example:

`setTimeout( window.location.reload.bind( window.location ), 1000 )`

Older IEs don't support explicit binding on host objects though.

You also get this for some native methods which are not generic such as:

```
var a = function(){}.toString;
a();
TypeError: Function.prototype.toString is not generic
```

Some are generic:

```
var fakeArray = {0:1,1:2,length:2};
fakeArray.join = [].join;
fakeArray.join( " " );
"1 2"
```

Answer (score 2):

This fails because you're missing the `location` context (the function's `this`), when passing it your way.
You would have to `bind` the context, before you can use it like this, for example with the [underscore.js bind method](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)

```
var boundReload = _.bind(window.location.reload, window.location);
setTimeout(boundReload, 500)
```

It's the same with any other function that is usually called from it's containing object like `console.log`

Comment: i would not suggest bringing in an entire library for a function that already exists natively anyways.

Comment: @jbabey you're right if you assume that the browser supports JavaScript 1.8.5, where `bind` was introduced. For backward compatibility I'd stick to underscore.js or, if one likes it, Prototype.

Comment: apply or call could (and probably should) be used instead of bind

Comment: `apply` and `call` would execute the `reload` function immediately, and I doubt that what goggin13 wanted ;)

Comment: you would put them in the anonymous function, just like he posted in his question

Comment: If you're using an anonymous function, there is no need for `apply` or `call`, you could just use `window.location.reload()`