# Sleep in Javascript via timeout?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, timeout, sleep, wait

I'd like to wait 1 minute and then execute a function *f()*. I have found out that in *Javascript* there isn't a *sleep()* function but I can use *setInterval()* or *setTimeout()* functions.

The *window.setInterval()* function works, but this is not what I want. I want to execute *f()* only once. I tried to use the *setTimeout()* [function](http://www.geekpedia.com/KB55_How-do-I-make-a-JavaScript-function-wait-before-executing-%28sleep-or-delay%29.html) as follows.

```
var MyNamespace {
  ...
  f: function() {
  },
  ...
  click: function() {
    ...
    setTimeout("this.f()", 60000); // f() is never executed
    // setTimeout(this.f(), 60000); f() is executed immediately without timeout
    // window.setTimeout(...) doesn't help
  },
  ...
}
```

What could be wrong here?

The code is part of a *Firefox* extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's your problem: `"this.f()"`. Replace it with:

```
setTimeout(this.f.bind(this), 60000);
```

and it should work. Passing a string to `setInterval()` is never a good solution, just like using `eval()`.

## See also

- [Why can't I pass "window.location.reload" as an argument to setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839989) - duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
setTimeout( this.f.bind(this), 60000 );
```

Never pass a string to `setTimeout` as it will be evaluated in global context.

Comment: Afaik, `bind` is not IE6-8 compatible.

Comment: @Oleg The code is for a firefox extension, and even if it wasn't you can make the used subset of `bind` in 3 lines of code.

Comment: Oh, that's right. Didn't notice... let's hope it's not for <FF4 then :)

Answer (score 1):

Also check out the nsiTimer if you're running the timer in chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsITimer

Answer (score 0):

As the code is intended for a firefox extensions you should use

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('timeout') },2000);

setTimeout(alert('timeout'),2000); // will be executed directly, not suitable
```