# jquery reload page after using ajax to update data

Tags: jquery, ajax, updates

I'm trying to find a way to reload the page after completing an `AJAX` update.

My Basic code is:

```
updateEdit = function() {
    $('#editSection').on('click', '#Changes', function() {  
        /*set var here*/
        $.ajaxSetup({ 
            data: {
                var1: 1,
                var2: 2
            }
        })
        ajaxUpdate();   
    });
}

ajaxUpdate = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            centerItem('#savedBox');
        },
        error: function(jqxhr) {
            alert(jqxhr.responseText);
        }
    })  
}
```

So far so good. I now need to pause for 1 second, then roload the page. Looking around suggests I need to use `setTimeout(location.reload, 1000);`

so I added in

```
complete: function() {
    setTimeout(location.reload, 1000);  
}
```

to the `$.ajaxsetup()` but that seemingly did nothing.
I then added it to the main `ajaxUpdate()` function, (not ideal as I don't want it to fire on every ajaxUpdate) whereby I got an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` error. (and no page reload). 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I pass "window.location.reload" as an argument to setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839989/why-cant-i-pass-window-location-reload-as-an-argument-to-settimeout)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10840058/1734119) should help you. Basically, you can't pass `location.reload` as is as an argument to `setTimeout`.

Comment: cheers, that explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax for setTimeout function is not correct

please use this:

```
setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reload is a method. Call it via a function

```
setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 1000);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
updateEdit = function() {
        ...

        // Will wait 1 sec and then reload the page
        var waitCallback = function () {
           setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, 1000);
        };

        ajaxUpdate(waitCallback);
    });
}

ajaxUpdate = function(cb) {
    $.get('update.php',
       function(data) {
          alert(data);
          centerItem('#savedBox');

          cb();
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr) {
            alert(jqxhr.responseText);
        });
};
```