# location.reload in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, typeerror, location-href

I'm trying to make the document reload when a button is clicked. Here's my code:

```
var e = document.getElementById('a');
e.addEventListener('click',location.reload);
```

It returns `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Invocation` after `e` was clicked. However, the following code works and the document reloaded:

```
var e = document.getElementById('a');//same thing
e.addEventListener('click',function(){location.reload()});
//warp location.reload inside function -> works!
```

I don't understand why the first code doesn't work. Can anyone give some explanation? Thanks!

Comment: In the first case, the second argument of your eventListener is not a function

Comment: @bugs yes it is. `window.location.reload` is a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I pass "window.location.reload" as an argument to setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839989/why-cant-i-pass-window-location-reload-as-an-argument-to-settimeout)

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `location.reload()` it not only calls function, but also sets `this` to the value of `location`, so these two are equivalent:

```
location.reload();
location.reload.call(location);
```

However, when you supply it to `addEventListener` only function reference is stored, but not the value of `this`, so when it's called it's equivalent to

```
location.reload.call(undefined); // strict mode
location.reload.call(window); // sloppy mode
```

For example Firefox provides a more clear error message: `TypeError: 'reload' called on an object that does not implement interface Location.`

As such for proper behavior you need to create a closure, or bind `this` to `location`, so both will work:

```
e.addEventListener('click', function(){location.reload()});
e.addEventListener('click', location.reload.bind(location));
```

Answer (score -3):

You're missing () from the recall function call in your first example. It should be:

> var e = document.getElementById('a'); e.addEventListener('click',location.reload());

Comment: No. That will cause the **return value** of `location.reload` to be passed as the callback function, not the function reference itself. It'll cause the page to refresh infinitely, because the function is being called each time the page loads (to obtain its return value), not each time the button is clicked...