# How to make page reload after 2 seconds if an "else" statement happens in javascript

Tags: javascript

So if i fail to login or user does not appear it will prompt a message failed to login or user not found and when that happens i wish the page to reload and go back to the login screen again, i tried with set timeout function but it does not seem to work. Thanks in advance

```
    if (error) {
        respond.json(error);
    } else {
        // If user can be found, result has one record
        if (result.length > 0) {
            if (input_password == result[0].user_password) {
                msg = "1"; // "Success!";
                console.log(msg);
            } else {
                msg = "Login Fail!";
                console.log(msg);
            }
        } else { // If user not found, result has no record
            setTimeout(function(){
            msg = "User not found!";

                window.location.reload(1);
             }, 2000);

        }
```

Comment: Something to consider: It is pretty well-established that authorisation should happen server-side, not in the browser.  Something to read up on: client-side vs server-side auth.  If you evaluate the risks and you're still fine with it, client side isn't wrong, just dangerous if you don't know the risks.  If this is just a learning assignment, for example, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using `window.location.reload(true)`;

It sounds like you need a reference to this.

[Why can't I pass "window.location.reload" as an argument to setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839989/why-cant-i-pass-window-location-reload-as-an-argument-to-settimeout)

So before you make the setTimeout save the reload function so it has the proper this.

```
var fun = window.location.reload(true);
setTimeout(function(){
            msg = "User not found!";

                fun();
             }, 2000);
```

So Bind it to

Comment: cant seem to work still i just get stuck at the failed to log in message screen

Comment: So please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839989/why-cant-i-pass-window-location-reload-as-an-argument-to-settimeout