# setTimeout(window.location.reload,1000) not working

Tags: javascript

Why does this not work?

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload, 1000)
```

This does

```
setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 1000)
```

The first parameter is a function. Shouldn't the first example work?

Comment: The error message is "illegal invocation".  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript.  The reason is that "reload" method needs context (which location object it's attached to).  You could use `window.location.reload.bind(window.location)` but that's longer than your alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing a loose reference to the `reload` function; therefore, losing its binding to `window.location`.

You can use the following to prove the point (It may not work

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 1000)
```

But I think adding a function wrapper makes it easier to understand.

**Example**

```js
const a = {
  value: 2,
  b: function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

a.b();

const b = a.b;
b();

const boundB = b.bind(a);
boundB();
```

**Summary**
Using syntax like `a.b()` makes sure that `b` is called with `a` as its `this`.

Calling a function without a `.` before will the function as a global, which will pass `window` as this in sloppy mode and `null` as `this` in strict mode.

This can always be overriden by binding function or by using arrow functions (which take its `this` from the surrounding `this`) or if you bind your function ahead of time.

Comment: why does it work this way, though? that's weird (or not?)

Comment: Because when you pass a loose reference to a function, you lose its binding to the property before it.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work as the scope of calling `window.location.reload` will be `window` instead of `window.location`.
Try this:

```
window.location.reload.call(window);
```

vs.

```
window.location.reload.call(window.location);
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `Function.bind`? Your code is trying to call the function immediately

Comment: You can examine the difference as it will be called with different scope. Bind can solve the issue if you want to pass reload as a reference

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how one would use your suggestion, you would still have to wrap it in a function and you are only adding keystrokes.

Comment: Suggestion? It was an answer to the original question why it is not working. It is a scoping issue, the answer was already in the question. He didnt ask how to make it work, but why it is not working that way.

Comment: You said "Try this". That is, you suggested that code. You probably meant to say that what will actually happen is the same as the first line but what they want is the second line. It is confusing.

Comment: Yes try this to see what is the problem, that was what I meant:) looks like not the best wording.

Answer (score 0):

This post sums it up nicely https://stackoverflow.com/a/10840058/10853009

> Because `reload()` needs `window.location` as `this`. In other words - it is
> a method of `window.location`. When you say:

```
var fun = window.location.reload;

fun();
```

> You are calling `reload()` function without any `this` reference (or with
> implicit `window` reference).